# Two inline buttons within a row of equal height and width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

[How to achieve this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/194dH.png) by using Bootstrap framework?

P.S. 2 buttons inline in cell and it's height = row.height and it's width = height.

```
<table id="mytable" class="table table-bordered tableEmployee">
<thead>
    <th>E-mail</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>tt@gmail.com
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spbsmile/jjawb8s7/)

Comment: Please create a fiddle or your problem or share your code.

Comment: provide sample code at-least so that we will be able to help you

Comment: add fiddle sample code @sumitchoudhary

Comment: what do mean by width=height . what exactly you want to achieve ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly remove the padding of the row.

```
table > tbody > tr > td, .table > tbody > tr > th, .table > tfoot > tr > td, .table > tfoot > tr > th, .table > thead > tr > td, .table > thead > tr > th {
  padding:0px !important;
}
```

Next give property to the button,tr,td.

```
td{
  height:40px; 
}

button{
  height:100%;  //height of button=height of td
  width:40px;   /manually assign the width same as td

}
```

take a peek at https://jsfiddle.net/sifat/jjawb8s7/3/

**or use javaScript**

`document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].offsetHeight` to get the height of the td and `document.getElementsById("button1").style.width`to assign width to it!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. inline button will have height same as row height.

```
<table id="mytable" class="table table-bordered tableEmployee">
<thead>
    <th>E-mail</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>tt@gmail.com
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs inline" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs inline" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

you can also set width as you want.